# JList Item Selection

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I was wondering if there is a way, by selecting an item with a JList, to let the program perform some code. This code should run every time a new item is selected.

Previously, I had added a listener. Here is a minimal example I made.

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ListFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200,100);
    }

}

public class ListFrame extends JFrame {

    private JList<String> list; 
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private String[] data = {"A","B","C"};
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");

    public ListFrame() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        list = new JList<String>(data);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String newEntry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add new entry.");
                String[] tempData = new String[data.length + 1];
                for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    tempData[i] = data[i];
                tempData[data.length] = newEntry;
                data = tempData;
                list = new JList<String>(data);
                scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
            }

        });

        list.addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Hi");
                    }

        });
    }
}
```

However, when I click an item on the Jlist, nothing is printed.

Comment: Google it buddy. You will get tons of links

Comment: See [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: I have updated my question with additional information. I have already tried the list selection listener.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example uses `getSelectionModel()` to get the the list's [`ListSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html), and it adds your listener directly to the selection model. This bypasses the `ListSelectionHandler`, used internally by [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), which never gets a chance to `fireSelectionValueChanged()`. Instead, let `JList` add your listener:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {...}
```

> when I click an item on the `JList`, nothing is printed.

Your new example prints "Hi" when I click an item, but I see some problems:

- Be sure to run on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Check the `ListSelectionEvent` for details of what happened.
- To add elements to the list, don't create a new `JList`; update the list's `ListModel` instead.

See [*How to Write a List Selection Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more; here's the example I tested.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new ListFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static class ListFrame extends JFrame {

        private final String[] data = {"A", "B", "C"};
        private final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        private final JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
        private final JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");

        public ListFrame() {
            for (String s : data) {
                model.addElement(s);
            }
            list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    String newEntry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add new entry.");
                    model.addElement(newEntry);
                }
            });
            list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                        System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex() + " " + e.getLastIndex());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added a minimal example. Could you look at the question again.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I took so long to respond.